# How to keep consecutive column when drop_duplicate is used in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to strip and drop duplicate rows from a specific column while keeping the other columns values. For example:

```
d_input = {'col1': ["a1-axa.spc", "a2-aea.spc","a2-ata.spc"], 'col2': [12, 2 ,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d_output = {'col1': ["a1", "a2"], 'col2': [12, 2 ]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have tried

```
df=df['col1'].str.replace('-.*?.spc', '')
```

and then

```
df= df.drop_duplicate()
```

but the final result is only a single column without the respective value on the COLUMN 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
s = df['col1'].str.replace('-.*?.spc', '', regex=True)

df = df.loc[~s.duplicated()].assign(col1=s)

# or
df = df.assign(col1=s).drop_duplicates('col1')
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0   a1    12
1   a2     2
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying the same code on a different dataframe (still same format) but I am getting this error: "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)." Any ideas?

Comment: maybe a duplicated index? Try the second approach: `df.assign(col1=s).drop_duplicates('col1')`

Comment: @Enyrb good news ;)